# Prove that if $\ K\subset\mathbb R ^n$ is compact and $\ F\subset K$ is closed then $\ F$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt:

Let$\ U$ be an open cover of$\ F$.

Every open subset of$\ U$ has the form $\ U\cap F$.

Let$\ V=(U\subset K : U$ is open and $\ \exists U' \in U $ such that $\ U \cap F = U'$ ) then$\ V$ is an open cover of$\ F$.

I'm stuck at this point, how can I go on with the proof? help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: to your open cover of $F$, at the complement of $F$ in $K$. Then use compactness on $K$ and throw out the open set you added, if necessary. This works for any compact $K$; it doesn't need to live in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your first few sentences. First you write "Let $U$ be an open cover of $F$." Okay, so say for the sake of example $U = \{O_1,O_2,\dotsc\}$, where $O_i$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then you write, "Every open subset of $U$" but what is an open subset of $U$? Is there a topology on $U$? Is the subset $\{O_1,O_3\}$ open or not? Then you mention "$U \cap F$" but $U$ and $F$ don't live in the same space, so what sense does it make to take an intersection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an open cover $O_\alpha$ of $F \subset K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. We see that because $F$ is closed, $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$ is open, and hence:
$$
(\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus F) \cup \bigcup _{\alpha}O_\alpha
$$
Forms an open cover of $K$ (it covers all of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ actually). We can extract a finite subcover of $K$ from this cover (because $K$ is compact), consisting of $O_1, \cdots ,O_n$ and then possibly $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$. Note then that the $O_1, \cdots , O_n$ have to cover $F$, because $(\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus F )\cap F = \emptyset$. We have shown then that for the open cover $O_\alpha$, we can extract a finite subcover, and the result follows.

Note that this statement is true in any topological space (any set where the terms "open", "closed" are defined) and hence is true outside of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R^n$, compactness is equivalent to be closed and bounded. So if $K$ is compact, $K$ is closed and bounded. $F \subset K$ must be bounded. It follows $F$ is compact.